Making nested fork() in C
I need to write a program in C that will:

create child process (child_process1)
print PID of parent process using getppid()
the child_process1 will create another subprocess (child_process2)
child_process2 will print PID of parent process (child_process1) using getppid() and its own PID using getpid()

So far, I've written something like that:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //declaration of PID holding variables
    pid_t child1, child2;
    pid_t child1_PID, child2_PID;
    //forking parent process
    child1 = fork();
    //redeclaring PID so as to omit double execution of code by both parent and child processes
    child1_PID = child1;
    //check whether child1_PID contains PID of a child process
    if(child1_PID == 0){
        //print PID of parent process
        printf("%d\n",getppid());
        //make child process child1 fork child process child2
        child2 = fork();
        //redeclaring PID so as to omit double execution of code by both parent and child processes
        child2_PID = child2;
        //check whether child2_PID contains PID of a child process
        if(child2_PID == 0){
            //print PID of parent process of child process child2 (child1)
            printf("%d\n",getppid());
            //print PID of child process child2
            printf("%d\n",getpid());
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

But the code doesn't seem to work the way I want. Furthermore, sometimes it prints 4 PIDs, sometimes only one.

Please elaborate "the code doesn't seem to work the way I want".

When you fork a new process, it will inherit everything from the parent process. And that includes the stdout buffers. That might mean that your output is not fully reliable.

On a different note, why do you have two sets of variables for the same thing? Like for example child1 and child1_PID? That comment about "redeclaration" doesn't make any sense.

Add setlinebuf(stdout); at top. And, maybe, fflush(stdout); before each fork call. Also, you need exit(0); as the last thing a child does. Those processes that do pid = fork(); need to do if (pid) waitpid(pid,NULL,0); near the end before any exit(0); call.

Modify your code so you identify each print operation (e.g. the first printf("%d\n", getppid()); could become printf("C1: PPID = %d\n", getppid());).  Adding this sort of information helps you see where the four values come from, or which single value you see.

Often, the issues in printf() anomaly after fork() are a part (or the cause) of the problem.  However, you seem to have avoided that, unless you run your program with its output redirected to a file or piped to a program.  The parent process should probably wait for all of its children to die before exiting itself.  I suspect scheduling issues are a part of the problem when you see just one output.  The first child process should probably wait for its children to die too.

I like to use a loop like int corpse; int status; while ((corpse = wait(&status)) != -1) print("%d: child %d exited 0x%.4X\n", getpid(), corpse, status); for the task; it reports which process is doing the waiting as well as which process died and its raw exit status.

The idea behind fork() is that you start with ONE process (your running program) and duplicate it.
Now you have TWO processes that are identical except for a single thing: the result of fork(). This is why you usually see a switch or if statements right after a fork(), so that each process can figure out whether it is the parent or not.
pid_t pid = fork();

if (pid < 0)
{
    printf( "fork() failed. There's still only one of me.\n" );
    exit( 1 );
}

if (pid == 0)
{
    printf( "I am the child. My parent's PID is %ld.\n", (long)getppid() );
}
else
{
    printf( "I am the parent. My child's PID is %ld.\n", (long)pid );
}

Remember, everything is duplicated. So you can have a variable that keeps track of how many times you have become the child.
int im_child_level = 0;  // 0 == not a child

...

if (pid == 0)
{
    // I am the child
    im_child_level += 1;
}

By watching that value you know how many times you have become a child (or, more accurately, how many levels deep of children you are), and can avoid forking too many times.
(Shawn just provided a nicer solution, but skipped the explanation. You should take the time to think about how both solutions work, and why his is nice.)

If you split it up into multiple functions instead of a bunch of deeply nested ifs, your code will be more organized and easier to read. Essentially, have the newly created child process call a function that does all the work of that child. You should also include some error checking and handling - what if fork() fails?
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void grandchild_func(void) {
  // pid_t might not be int; cast it to avoid issues with printf
  printf("Grandchild's parent pid is %d and its own pid is %d\n",
         (int)getppid(), (int)getpid());
  exit(0);
}

void child_func(void) {
  printf("Child's parent pid is %d\n", (int)getppid());
  fflush(stdout);  // make sure grandchild doesn't get a copy of the current
                   // stdout buffer so the above doesn't get printed twice.
  pid_t grandchild = fork();
  if (grandchild == 0) {
    grandchild_func();
  } else if (grandchild < 0) {
    perror("child fork");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  } else {
    waitpid(grandchild, NULL, 0);
  }
  exit(0);
}

int main(void) {
  pid_t child = fork();
  if (child == 0) {
    // child process; let it do its thing
    child_func();
  } else if (child < 0) {
    // error; no child created
    perror("parent fork");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  } else {
    // parent process; wait for child to exit
    waitpid(child, NULL, 0);
  }
  return 0;
}


Waiting for the child processes to end in the parents isn't really necessary in such a trivial case as this, but in anything complicated or long running it's a good idea so you can detect and handle abnormal exits of the children, and avoid zombie processes.
